# Query where object method equals a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have a table called Notes. You can call a method called 'book' on a note (book is not a column on the Notes table).

If i do `Note.first.book.author.id`, it gives the author id. however, when trying to query Notes to find all notes where author id = '123', where I try

`Note.where(book.author.id = '123')` I get an error ***undefined local variable or method `book'***

Can i not query using a method in this way? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You are calling undefined variable `book` and trying to pass the result to `where` method, that's why it causes an error. If you run just `book.author.id = '123'` you'll get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `Book` model relates to `Note` through `book_id` column inside `notes` table, and `author_id` is a column inside `books` table, then the query should look like this:

```
Note.includes(:book).where(books: { author_id: 123 })
```

Here is the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Note.joins(book: :author).where(book: { author: { id: 123 } })
```